# How to replace json vault from xhr?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need help how to replace json vault from json file at web with javascript xhr?

setagaya.json:

```
{"trains":[{"operation_number":1,"line_id":26007,"station_id":784,"track_number":1,"up":true},{"operation_number":2,"line_id":26007,"station_id":1015,"track_number":-1,"up":false},{"operation_number":3,"line_id":26007,"station_id":1012,"track_number":-1,"up":false},{"operation_number":4,"line_id":26007,"station_id":1009,"track_number":-1,"up":false},{"operation_number":5,"line_id":26007,"station_id":1009,"track_number":1,"up":true},{"operation_number":6,"line_id":26007,"station_id":1012,"track_number":1,"up":true},{"operation_number":7,"line_id":26007,"section_id":217,"up":false}],"delays":null}
```

code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var output = "<h2>Setagaya Line</h2><table><tr><th>&nbspJalur&nbsp</th><th>Nomer Operasional</th><th>Posisi Ruas</th><th>Posisi Statiun</th><th>Posisi Jalur</th><th>Arah</th>";
        for (var i in myObj.trains) {
            output += "<tr><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].line_id + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].operation_number + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].section_id + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].station_id + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].track_number + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].up + "</center></td ></tr > ";
        }
        document.getElementById("setagaya").innerHTML = output;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "setagaya.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

this code only gets the JSON, now I need to replace the value.

So, I want the 26007 at line_id to Setagaya Line, 943 at station_id to Sangenjaya, 1012 at station_id to Setagaya, 784 at station_id to Shimotakaido, 217 at section_id to Matsubara-Yamasita

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace it in the file save - I mean, edit the file and save it?

Comment: In your last paragraph you mention `943 at station_id to Sangenjaya`. However the values **`943`** and **`Sangenjaya`** are nowhere else present in your code or data, what are they supposed to mean or where are they supposed to come from? Similar for `217 at section_id to Matsubara-Yamasita` but now also `section_id` is unclear because it appears nowhere, except in the last paragraph. Please **[edit]** the question and clarify! Also, a last remark: what do you mean by **`vault`**? I know `vault` as a big metal box to keep valuable stuff in (money, jewelry, etc), how is it related to JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define all the mappings you have in mind as objects:

```
let lines = {
    26007: "Setagaya Line"
};
let stations = {
     943: "Sangenjaya", 
     1012: "Setagaya",
     784: "Shimotakaido"
};
let sections = {
    217: "Matsubara-Yamasita"
};
```

Extend as needed.

Also define a utility function:

```
function getVal(obj, prop) {
    return prop in obj ? obj[prop] : prop || "";
}
```

This will get the value for a given property from a given object. If the property is not defined by the object, then the property itself is returned. If also that property is not defined, then the empty string is returned.

Finally change your loop to:

```
for (var i in myObj.trains) {
    output += "<tr><td><center>" + getVal(lines, myObj.trains[i].line_id)
        + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].operation_number 
        + "</center></td><td><center>" + getVal(sections, myObj.trains[i].section_id) 
        + "</center></td><td><center>" + getVal(stations, myObj.trains[i].station_id) 
        + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].track_number 
        + "</center></td><td><center>" + myObj.trains[i].up + "</center></td></tr>\n";
}
```